# Retrieve requested GraphQL field without waiting for parent resolve using graphql-java-tools

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm looking to optimise a GraphQL endpoint running on `graphql-java` and `graphql-java-tools`.

I have the following schema:

```
{
  product(id: String) {
    id
    title
    offer {
      price
    }
  }
}
```

`id` and `title` come from service A, price comes from service B.

Right now, I have a `GraphQLQueryResolver` that returns a `CompletableFuture<ProductResponse>` where `ProductResponse` contains `id` and `title`, and I have another `GraphQLResolver<ProductResponse>` with a method `offer(ProductResponse productResponse)` that returns a `CompletableFuture<OfferResponse>`.

However, this means that I have to wait for service A to return a `ProductResponse` to begin to query service B for an `OfferResponse`. Both services only need the ID as input and thus could be executed in parallel.
Is there any way to execute both service calls in parallel without adjusting the schema?

Answer (score 0):

In ProductFieldResolver, you need to return a CompletableFuture for id, CompletableFuture for name and CompletableFuture for Offers object. And inside each of the method implementation , call the dataloader of respective service. by that way it will be parallely executed.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can consider using Apollo federation which solves it in a generic manner but still in an elegant way.

Try going through this - https://github.com/apollographql/federation-demo

Comment: Apollo is written in javascript; here the original poster mentionned `graphql-java-tools` in the title + added `graphql-java` as tag.